# Ethernet routing, through-wall conduits

Tags: security, cable-management

I'm looking to install a PoE camera system. The system comes with 8 cameras and the Ethernet cables will mostly be routed *on* ceilings and walls (not within them). I have some questions about making neat exits through walls.

I'll install the system in a utility room and I'd like a batch of 8 cables to exit directly from that room and into the adjacent garage, where they'll be mostly routed across the ceiling on raceways.

1. Is there a product to serve as a tidy through-wall conduit for a collection of cables. For example: PVC pipe, but with some sort of flange that screws to each side of the drywall? Would such a wall penetration be a fire-code concern (as it may allow some airflow)?
2. At the camera-end, I'd like to pass cables through a wall and directly into the back of the camera on the other side. How can I make a neat through-wall connection here? I've seen [bushings for coax (which would work for Ethernet)](https://www.showmecables.com/bushing-for-single-coax-white?gclid=CjwKCAjwvMqDBhB8EiwA2iSmPPI03mZxJ3OJIVPshYgzmWP1Jjzt4jl7jWVGGwXa_sgjmK4Zgx36hxoCez4QAvD_BwE), however, in some cases, there may be a 10" drop from the ceiling to the penetration, which I think will mean the cable will have to 'dangle' in the air to avoid sharp turns (which are not recommended for Ethernet, particularly for long-runs).

**Is there a better (*tidier*) solution?** (*I prefer PoE over WiFi because there is no power for the WiFi cameras*).

[image]

Comment: Wireless, battery powered Wifi Cameras  are available.

Answer (score 1):

At the camera end at a bow and an outlet cover with an ethernet socket (e.g. [image]

That will look neat and be great if you need to change the camera's at some point in the future.

Jonathan

Comment: How are these implemented into the OP's design plan?  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The faceplate above fits in a standard single gang box. You would buy a reel of ethernet cable, the faceplates, and a small patch panel. It's pretty easy to wire up the ethernet cable to the faceplate / patch panel. See https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/ethernet-ieee-802-3/cables-types-pinout-cat-5-5e-6.php

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom end add a patch panel. something like [image]

This makes it real easy when you need to change things in the future.

Jonathan

Comment: A good suggestion but it is not an answer to the question. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer